# How to Register an image picker?

Tags: python

[image: screenshot of a panel]

I want to register an image picker in a panel. How Can i do it?
The example code is here:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.prop_search(context.scene, 'image_name', bpy.data, 'images')
        row.operator("image.open", icon="FILE_FOLDER", text="")

        

def register():
    from bpy.types import Scene, Image
    Scene.my_image = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name="Image", type=Image)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Goal is to replicate the dropdown in the header of the *Image Editor*?

Comment: `row.prop(scene, 'my_image')`  would also do the trick/